# Reactjs button is looking "stuck" after click

Tags: reactjs

Using these buttons:
https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/button/

When pressing the button it slightly changes color to indicate it was pressed. However this color change is sticky, almost like the button is selected until I press somewhere else that is not the button. Is it possible to make the button color change go back after a second or so?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The button became active. Try changing the `:active` psuedoselector in CSS to change what active buttons look like.

Comment: If you group the buttons (e.g. in a CRow or CButtonGroup) then this is the behaviour. Only one button is selected at a time.

Comment: Did the answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

When the goal is to change the color of a button the way you described we should make use of the pseudo class `:active`. However, coreui uses the pseudo class `:focus`, hence the difference.

I can think of two solutions:
1 - you change focus programmatically with a `setTimeout` function after a click.
2 - manually overwrite coreui from `:focus` to `:active`.